# why does a javascript global variable within function show an error?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I put a global variable within numPrinter function in Javascript.

but if I don't put `numPrinter();` before putting `console.log(i);`

it is `a global variable`.. `global`..
and also I don't understand how `global variable` works after `numPrinter()`

there's no `return i;` within `numPrinter();`

```
var numPrinter = function(){

    i = 30;
};

console.log(i);  // ReferenceError: i is not defined

numPrinter();
console.log(i);  // 30
```

Comment: It appears you haven't declared `i` anywhere (with `var` or `let`), so when you just say `i = 30` inside `numPrinter`, this "magically" declares `i` as a global variable and sets it to 30. (This is a strange quirk of Javascript that usually just causes problems, you can avoid it by using strict mode.) So the first time you log `i`, the variable isn't declared in any accessible scope, hence the `ReferenceError` - then `numPrinter()` "magically" creates the global `i` and sets it to 30.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks. but I don't get how `numPrinter()` can create the global i

Comment: As I sad, this is a "feature" (a bad one!) of Javascript (when not run in strict mode). I'm not sure how much more I can say, but here is a link to MDN where it's mentioned (3rd paragraph): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are the JavaScript engine, reading this code from the top-down:

1. The first thing we read is the `numPrinter` function. There are no `()` present, so `numPrinter` is only defined but not invoked.
2. Continuing down, the first `console.log(i);` is read. Calling it here results in `ReferenceError: i is not defined` because `numPrinter` still has NOT been invoked so `i` can't be accessed yet.
3. Further down, we encounter `numPrinter();` Here, the JS engine reads the `()` and invokes the `numPrinter` function. We now have access to `i` because undeclared variables always become global variables.
4. Lastly, the second `console.log(i);` is read and prints out the result of `30` because `i` is globally accessible outside of the `numPrinter` function.

Answer (score -1):

By default variables in js are global, so if you write smth like:

```
let i = 30
```

in your function, it will be local